# "Say" and "said" as transitive and intransitive verbs

Tags: speech, transitive-verbs, dialogue, intransitive-verbs

I have an interesting question. Is "say" a transitive verb in the case of direct/reported speech? I understand that it *can* be a transitive verb in cases like "She said the phrase." or "She says the words quietly.". But what about:

Bob looked at his fried and said, "You are my best buddy."
Or, "I know that," said his friend.

My thought process on this is that the direct/reported speech instance is not representing the use of the verb "say" as transitive, as it is a separate dialogue tag with no direct object. However, I think this all moves into the realm of what we believe the role of speech is in grammatical structure in the first place, which I don't know about you, but I have mixed thoughts on in the first place.

Comment: The full OED has as its first definition ***transitive** - To utter aloud (a **specified word or words**, or an articulate sound). Also of a writer: to be the author of (the **quoted word or words**).* After which they give many example usages of the general form ***"[exact words spoken]", said [speaker]***. But I can't help noticing their citations mostly seem to feature "American" style punctuation (commas / periods / etc.  that are syntactically bound to the sentence *containing* the directly quoted speech are placed *within* the quote-delimited text, not *after* it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the reference and answer. However, do you think their using of the American style means anything to our topic?

Speaking as to that, you example has the comma on the outside. Is that not British style?

Comment: Yes, the way I punctuated the example in my comment is "British style". I only flagged that point up because I couldn't quickly identify an example to cut&paste from the OED entry that *didn't* use "American style". I'm resigned to *reading* things like ***"Do me a favor," said John*** - but if I'm *writing,* I'll stick to ***"Do me a favour", said John**.* As to whether that's *relevant*, I guess some people will think it is, and some won't. To my mind, the quote marks are there to delineate the actual utterance being cited, within which "containing sentence-level" punctuation has no place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I like your thought process on all this. However, I do have to ask something: If you logic prevails, why not just skip the comment altogether? Additionally, if your logic is the inner text is not governed by the punctuation on the outside, where does your views on capitalization of inner starting text. Ex. I looked at her and said, "That's my blouse.'. Why capitalize "That's"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers And I guess the second part of that is how you reason with having punctuation in the quotes if there are multiple sentences, when you have to separate them by periods but they're all still in the quote?

Comment: *Why capitalize "That's"?* Approximately, *because we speak and write in "sentences"*. And a sentence starts with a capital letter, even if it happens to be embedded within a "containing" sentence (as, say, the "object" of ***say*** in the current context). But yeah - I could have forgone posting these comments, just as you could have foregone responding. The bottom line though is that I don't agree with your point about ***say*** somehow being *a separate dialogue tag with no direct object*. I say it's a ***verb***, which by all normal definitions is almost always ***transitive***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I could see someone arguing both ways, to be honest. Thank you for your input and answers!

Comment: No, the verb is not transitive. In your first example, "you are my best buddy" is **complement** of the reporting verb "said". In your second example, "I know that" is the main clause and "said his friend" is a parenthetical.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for your input, BllJ, as always. However, if you would be so kind to share some further on the expanded discussion between me and FF, I would be eternally grateful. Most specifically, if the first example is called out as a complement, why do we capitalize the first word, while in other sentences, where the quote seems to be more closely integrated into syntax (ex. Bob said that "ice cream cones are essential".) we do not.

Comment: What's capitalized (and how we order our punctuation marks) is a question of typography, not grammar.

Comment: It's pretty much standard to begin direct reported speech with a capital letter irrespective of its syntactic function. It's a complement because it's obligatory: "Bob looked at his friend and said" cannot stand alone as a sentence. By contrast, in indirect speech such as your ex "that ice cream cones are essential", has the form of a subordinate _that_ clause and hence not capaitalised.

Comment: @BillJ But, being a complement isn't necessarily the reasoning behind its capitalization correct? Additionally, is "that ice cream cones are essential" not obligatory also?